# Can we please make the watched tag highlighting contrast a little more?

Tags: feature-request, design

At the moment, this is what questions with a watched tag look like, compared to a question without a watched tag:

[image: screenshot of two questions on the homepage, one with a watched tag and one without]

I find this... very hard to see the difference. The contrast is so small that if I'm scrolling through the front page, I can't tell the difference without tilting my screen back and looking up at the screen oddly.

This is also *completely* not easy to use for anyone who has a bit of trouble telling slight differences in color apart.

Could we make the contrast a *little* more obvious, please?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283871/darker-color-for-favorite-tags https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319494/change-shade-color-for-watched-tags-on-stack-overflow  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283674/color-for-favorite-tags-questions-on-new-so-design-needs-to-be-stronger https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/can-we-change-the-contrast-of-questions-which-have-at-least-one-of-our-favourite   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278354/favorite-tag-highlighting https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313489/390967

Comment: I have a slight memory of Catija saying this is already on their to do list but in either case why not post this on main meta where it would get more attention?

Comment: According to the powers-that-be, they're already "[look(ing) at accessibility early next year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319503/262849)".